# Using react with a html template

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

I bought a HTML template on theme forest. I would like to use react with it. How do I go about implementing react with this template? I am able to do this with angular easy, but I would like to learn React.

Comment: So learn React (The same way as you did with Angular, but using React tutorials) and implement it. Question asking for tutorial recommendations are off topic and most likely doomed to closure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cut your template into components and replace `class` attribute with `className`.

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="my-class">
        Hello, world!
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Take a look at official [tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html)
But I strongly recommend you to read the documentation first and only then ask specific questions about what you did not understand.